# Equal distant scale ticks in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following x axis scale:

[250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000]

The numbers should be plotted on the x axis as ticks. The data coming in will only ever have one of the above values on the x axis. I need all the ticks to be equal in width.

I have attempted to work with d3.scale.quantize, but I'm confused how that would integrate w/ d3.svg.axis because the range is no longer a 0 to max width amount and instead bucketed values.

Any ideas?

for reference, trying to make this: http://www.sfu.ca/sonic-studio/handbook/Graphics/Audiogram.gif

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? You shouldn't need to change anything wrt the axis code. You could also use an ordinal scale.

Answer (score 0):

Ah so using an ordinal scale as Lars mentioned in the comment to my question w/ rangePoints for proper width was what I was looking for. Something like...

```
labels = [250, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000]
@x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(labels).rangePoints([0, @config.width])
```